# Hide all children of CS5 object in AS3 code

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, movieclip

I have MovieClip, created with CS5. Is there a way to hide (set visible = false) all it's children (objects which lie on movie clip) within AS3 code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i:int = clip.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    clip.getChildAt(i).visible = false;
}
```