# Toggle the menu items and hide all other submenus

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sdk, articulate-storyline

So last week the SDK from Articulate-Storyline was finaly published, and you can download it for free here: http://www.articulate.com/support/storyline/articulate-storyline-sdk. Now someone can customes the player for Articulate. There is already one example in the folder which I want to Edit. But the language is AS3 and I do not have a lot of experience with that. What I want is, that the subitems at the sidebar menu should only be shown at the one that the user clicked. So if one is open and the user clicks on another on, everything should close, except the one that has just been clicked.

Since there is nothing I could read myself through (except learning AS3), I would be so thankful for a helpful answer!

Comment: Frustrating as it may be, you'll have give a stab at coding in AS3 before you'll find much help.  I can say, you're probably looking to iterate over the child elements of the `sidebar`, and hide the ones you don't want (perhaps simply by moving them offscreen).  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995421/hide-all-children-of-cs5-object-in-as3-code

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do have little skills in AS3, but unfortunatly not enough :( I found the Menuscripts in this folder: src\customframe\panels\menu and I have already tried to simply hide all other childs, but for showing and hiding there is an extra class, where I have no access to the other childs. grml...